# the value of the textbox created in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

how to get the value of the textbox created in while loop in the same page  onchange event in php

```
while($fet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{    
    echo '<tr onchange=loadXMLDoc2(this)>';
    echo '<td><input type=text id=hello name=hello data-id='.$fet["username"].' onchange=loadXMLDoc1(this.value,this,"hello"); value='.$fet["username"].'>';
    echo '<td><input type=text id=uid name=uid onchange=loadXMLDoc1(this.value,this,"uid") value='.$fet["id"].'>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set a different id for each textbox.

```
echo '<td><input type=text id='+some_id+'...'
```

Then, you will be able to get the textbox value in javascript using `document.getElemenyById('some_id').value`
Also, you're using `onchange=func(this.value)`. This would also work, although theis method is [less recommended](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html).

Comment: I believe he means he wants the value in PHP, but his question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your code:

1) Assigning static IDs in a loop will create duplicated IDs, which is invalid in HTML. You don't need IDs for the `onchange` to work in the way you did, so you can remove them. If you need the IDs for another reason, the add some counter to them. Something like `id=hello$i`.

2) Using `onchange` will cause the xml doc to be loaded for every keystroke. Is that really what you want? If you actually want to load the xml doc only once when the user enters the entire value, then consider using `onblur`.

Other than that, your use of this.value seems fine. If it is not working as you expect, then explain what you are getting, so we can help you.

Comment: id=hello$i how can i get this value in javascript

Comment: As I said, you don't need it for the `onchange` in the way you did it. Do you need it for other reason?

Comment: If you want to get the value in any event of the input (e.g. `onchange`), you can use `this.value` and no need for the id. If you need to get the value in some JavaScript code other than the events of the input, you will have to use something like: `document.getElementById("hello" + 5).value`. Replace 5 with the number of the input that you want the value from.